# Python : How to reverse the order of sublist in a list?

Tags: python, list, reverse

I have a list which is made up of nested lists. I want to rearrange the order of sublists. I tried using the `list.reverse()` method, however it reverses the elements of the sublist. I want to reverse just the order of sublist rather than the elements.

```
Input : [['25', '9', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00'], ['26', '11', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00']]
Expected Output : [['26', '11', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00'],['25', '9', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00']]
```

Comment: what did you try already and what was wrong with it?

Comment: I tried this code, entry = entry[::-1]
The output I got was : 
['17.00', 'toaster_1', 'BID', '9', '25']
['17.00', 'toaster_1', 'BID', '11', '26']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
initial_list=[['25', '9', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00'], ['26', '11', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00']]
modified_list=initial_list[::-1] #reverse the list
print(modified_list)
```

**The 2nd line in the code reverse the list.From index value -1**

Comment: That just looks like an inefficient unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I used `array.reverse()` and it worked as you wanted.

[The test](https://repl.it/@Bben01/CompassionateDarkorangeRam#main.py)

```py
Output: [['26', '11', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00'], ['25', '9', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '17.00']]
```

Comment: maybe because I am running this inside a for loop, does it make any difference? let me try it outside for loop

Comment: @user6662097 Yes it makes a difference.

Comment: @user6662097 Sounds like you maybe shouldn't reverse the list at all, but just iterate it in reverse?

Comment: Hi, how to iterate a list in reverse?

Comment: @user6662097 Are you talking to me? You didn't address=notify me. `for sublist in reversed(mylist): ...`.